# Secure application roles and SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm working with secure application roles to grant access to users. In its dumbest form, it looks like that:

```
create or replace package body main_user.PACK_SAR is
procedure grant_role is
begin
    dbms_session.set_role('TEST_ROLE');
end;
end PACK_SAR;
```

The package is in `authid current_user`, as it should be.
The role and user are configured as follow:

```
create role test_role identified using pack_sar;
grant select on task to test_role;

create user test_user identified by a;
grant create session to test_user;
grant execute on pack_sar to test_user;
```

Then I login with my `test_user`, call the procedure and everything is fine:

```
execute main_user.pack_sar.grant_role;
select * from main_user.task;
[... data from the task table ...]
```

But now I would like to use my test user with SQL*Loader, so I thought I'm going to do the procedure call in an `after logon` trigger:

```
create or replace trigger test_user.after_logon
after logon on test_user.schema
begin
    main_user.pack_sar.grant_role;
end;
```

But this does not seem to do anything, I don't get the role after login... Is there any way to do something like this? Or is using secure application roles within SQL*Loader impossible?

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 
[this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=624066)

at the bottom.